# Sum columns in 2D result set with CosmosDB

Tags: arrays, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm currently working on a project where I need to query a lot of documents in a CosmosDB instance (>100.000) and sum all columns in the values array. Let me give en example.

Documents:

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "values": [ 10, 12, 18, 12 ]
},
{
    "id": "5678",
    "values": [ 12, 10, 9, 14 ]
}
```

Result should be an array of all columns in the values arrays, so something like this:

```
[10, 12, 18, 12]
[12, 10,  9, 14]
---------------
[22, 22, 27, 26]
```

Currently I only have the following solution:

```
SELECT SUM(c.values[0]) as v1, SUM(c.values[1]) as v2, SUM(c.values[2]) as v3, SUM(c.values[3]) as v4 FROM c
```

But problem is that the values array is an array of 100 values, so the query becomes very unreadable then.

Any idea how I can fix this in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant way I can think of is to write logical code in the cosmos db stored procedure.

SP code:

```
function sample(test) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT v as item FROM c join v in c.values',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            var array = [0,0,0,0];
            var count = 0;
            for(var i=0;i<feed.length;i++){                
                if(count>3)
                    count = 0;
                array[count] = array[count] + feed[i].item;
                count++;
            }
            response.setBody(array);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Output:

[image]